# Core ui select not working for mobile users

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am using the script "core ui select" to style my forms on my website. Everything was working fine for desktop users, but since a while there is a lot of reports from users using mobiles. They say that they can't modify the  option because it is greyed out.

So i did the test using a firefox plugin called "Default User Agent" and i switched my browser agent to iPhone. Then i realised that the whole form stopped working, but only for mobile users

Here's a test page if you want to see the problem live (you would have to change your user agent to reproduce the bug) :
https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/test_mobile.php

And here's the code of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.no-gods-no-masters.com/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.no-gods-no-masters.com/scripts/css/core-ui-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://www.no-gods-no-masters.com/scripts/css/jquery.scrollpane.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#impression').coreUISelect();
    });
    </script>
</head><body>

<select class="b-core-ui-select__dropdown" name="impression" id="impression">
<option>Printing on front</option>
<option>Printing on back</option>
</select>

<script src="https://www.no-gods-no-masters.com/scripts/js/jquery.core-ui-select.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just realised that even the demo page of the Core UI select script has this bug... So this isn't a bug with my website but with core-ui-select script... Does anybody know how to fix this ? I can pay for the work

Comment: UI core isn't really designed for mobile. You could try this: http://touchpunch.furf.com/ I added this little script to use the uicore slider and worked perfectly on all mobile devices I had to test, including iPAD, iPhone, Samsung galaxy s3-4-5. Hope that helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. When executing on a mobile device, the plugin (core-ui-select) explicitly skips the DOM manipulation code which is meant to show the dropdown.
To see this, you can set a break point in jquery.core-ui-select.js line number 176.

```
CoreUISelect.prototype.showDropdown = function() {
        this.domSelect.focus();
        this.settings.onOpen && this.settings.onOpen.apply(this, [this.domSelect, 'open']);
        if($.browser.mobile) return this; //176: this skips the rest on mobile
        if(!this.isSelectShow) {
            this.isSelectShow = true;
            this.select.addClass('open');
            this.dropdown.addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
            if(this.isJScrollPane) this.initJScrollPane();
            this.scrollToCurrentDropdownItem(this.dropdownItem.eq(this.getCurrentIndexOfItem()));
            this.updateDropdownPosition();
        }
    }
```

The evaluation on line 176: `$.browser.mobile` evaluates to true when tapped (I simulated a mobile device in Chrome) and the remainder code is thus skipped.

**Fix**: Removing the line shows the drop-down just fine.